# show tags on "single"-template sidebar only

Tags: tags, sidebar

If a post has tags, I would like to show only those tags as a list in the sidebar when viewing the single post; how do I do this?

I have searched to find a suitable plugin, but didn't find one, as all the ones I've looked up end up showing every tags on the site or for categories.

I'm happy to go with a non-plugin solution.

Comment: Plugin, Theme  and hosting recommendations are off topic on this site.

Comment: Thank you kaiser. Will bear the guidelines in mind for future quereis.My query is to find a way achieve the result without using a plugin, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will display the tags of the current post in an unordered list:

```
<?php is_single() && the_tags( '<ul class="tags"><li>', '</li><li>', '</li></ul>' ) ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags

You'll most likely want to drop this in `sidebar.php`.

Comment: I couldn't see a sidebar.php in my template. So i added this in a widget to appear on the sidebar. Works great! Thanks